# Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML in Next.js

Tags: reactjs, next.js, i18next

I have four error after using getStaticProps and getStaticPaths

My dynamic page name is [blogId] in address  http://localhost:3000/blog/[someThing]

```
export async function getStaticProps({ locale,context }) {
    
    const {params} = context
    const BlogId = params.blogId
    
    const blogItems = blogData.find(i => i.id === BlogId)
    return {
      props: {
        ...(await serverSideTranslations(locale,blogItems)),

      },
    };
  }

export async function getStaticPaths() {
    return {
      paths: [
      
        {params:{ blogId: '1'},},
        {params:{ blogId: '2'},},
    ],
      fallback: true
    }
  }

export default function Home(props) {
 
    const { t } = useTranslation();
    let router = useRouter();
    const blogData = t("blogList:blog", { returnObjects: true });

  return (
    <>
        <h1>{blogItems.date}</h1>
    </>
  );
}
```

when I go to address it shows me 404 page and gives me 4 error

1- Error: Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

2-Error: Hydration failed because the initial UI does not match what was rendered on the server.

3-Error: There was an error while hydrating. Because the error happened outside of a Suspense boundary, the entire root will switch to client rendering.

4-Error: Failed to load static props

How can I solve that?

Comment: Have you found any solution?

Comment: do you have any update on that?